# How to Create Vector in R using certain conditions

Tags: python, r

I need to create a Vector in R with following requirements:

Total 12 elements in the vector. Value of first element is 100. Remaining elements to be increased by 5% over the previous element.

So output required:

```
c(100, 105, 110.25, 115.76, 121.55, 127.63, 134.01, 140.71, 147.75, 155.13, >162.89, 171.03).
```

eg.
   `105=100 X 1.05`
   `110.25=105 X 1.05`
   `115.76=110.25 X 1.05` and so on.

Should I first create an empty vector AND THEN iterate through each vector component with for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No for loop is needed.

```
100*1.05^(0:11)

# [1] 100.0 105.0 110.2 115.8 121.6 127.6 134.0 140.7 147.7 155.1 162.9 171.0
```

Of course for loops are embedded in the ":" function described in the [source here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/98b276109f0280296fffda9830e89ac9414cb762/src/main/seq.c) lines 114:144.

Comment: `100*1.05^(0:11)` to be precise about required output.

Answer (score 3):

```
cumprod(rep(1.05, 12)) * 100

[1] 105.0000 110.2500 115.7625 121.5506 127.6282 134.0096 140.7100 147.7455 155.1328 162.8895 171.0339 179.5856
```

Making a function can be handy:

```
f1 <- function(start, count, multiplier){
  c(start, cumprod(rep(multiplier, (count-1))) * start)
}


f1(100, 12, 1.05)

[1] 100.0000 105.0000 110.2500 115.7625 121.5506 127.6282 134.0096 140.7100 147.7455 155.1328 162.8895 171.0339 179.5856
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a classic `for` loop option.  In `R`, vectorized methods are more efficient, but `for` loops can be used in most of the programming languages with minimal changes in code.  Also, the source code in most of the functions have loops.

```
v1 <- c(100, numeric(11))
for(i in 2:length(v1)) {
    v1[i] <- v1[i-1] + v1[i-1]*0.05
}

round(v1, 2)
#[1] 100.00 105.00 110.25 115.76 121.55 127.63 134.01 140.71 147.75 155.13 162.89 171.03
```

Or use a `R` style coding with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x,y) round(x + x*0.05, 2), v1, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 100.00 105.00 110.25 115.76 121.55 127.63 134.01 140.71 147.75 155.14 162.90 171.05
```